# Examples for intelligent, brillant, smart, talented, wisdom and genius?

Tags: american-english, synonyms

Out of the terms

intelligent,
brilliant,
smart,
talented,
wisdom,
genius

Which are the ones that are natural (by genetics) and which are the ones that are developed by practice? Also, which are the ones required to practice others? Please give concrete examples to convey the meaning of the above words.

Comment: If you do happen to understand the meanings of those words, then this Q is out of the scope of the English language. OTOH if you would like to know how the meanings of the words relate to their inborn/ cultivated nature, you should rephrase accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison should be between intelligent, brilliant, smart, talented, genius and **wise.**

As all others are adjectives while wisdom is a noun.

All of the above require a fair amount of in-born qualities.

If we go by genetics, intelligence, talent and genius (which is essentially an IQ score of 160 or higher by some and 200 of higher by everybody) are definitely inborn. Brilliant  falls into the same category.

Smart definitely requires intelligence but also worldly wisdom. One of the common phrases is street-smart, which could be an acquired trait.Smart can also be used to describe a certain trait. However I have also found smart to be used interchangeably with intelligent at times.

Wisdom is acquired. The dictionary definition of the word is:
*the quality of having experience, knowledge, and good judgement; the quality of being wise.*

All the other words can be explained contextually, as shades and hues of the words can acquire different meanings.